# Spark unionAll multiple dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For a set of dataframes

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(1 to 4).map(i => (i,i*10)).toDF("id","x")
val df2 = sc.parallelize(1 to 4).map(i => (i,i*100)).toDF("id","y")
val df3 = sc.parallelize(1 to 4).map(i => (i,i*1000)).toDF("id","z")
```

to union all of them I do

```
df1.unionAll(df2).unionAll(df3)
```

Is there a more elegant and scalable way of doing this for any number of dataframes, for example from

```
Seq(df1, df2, df3)
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The simplest solution is to `reduce` with `union` (`unionAll` in Spark < 2.0):

```
val dfs = Seq(df1, df2, df3)
dfs.reduce(_ union _)
```

This is relatively concise and shouldn't move data from off-heap storage <s>but extends lineage with each union</s> requires non-linear time to perform plan analysis. what can be a problem if you try to merge large number of `DataFrames`.

You can also convert to `RDDs` and use `SparkContext.union`:

```
dfs match {
  case h :: Nil => Some(h)
  case h :: _   => Some(h.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
                     h.sqlContext.sparkContext.union(dfs.map(_.rdd)),
                     h.schema
                   ))
  case Nil  => None
}
```

It keeps <s>lineage short</s> analysis cost low but otherwise it is less efficient than merging `DataFrames` directly.

Comment: Thanks for all these approaches!

Comment: Is this as simple in scala ? What would it be ?

Comment: How would the equivalent of this code be in pySpark?

Comment: How is the performance is there are lots (say, more than 20) of DataFrames?

Comment: Also curious in performance for large number of DF

Answer (score 122):

For pyspark you can do the following:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
```

**It's also worth noting that the order of all the columns in all the dataframes in the list should be the same for this to work.  This can silently give unexpected results if you don't have the correct column orders!!**

If you are using pyspark 2.3 or greater, you can use unionByName so you don't have to reorder the columns.

Comment: Please remember the point mentioned in bold.

Comment: Using Python's `reduce` means that the operations don't occur in parallel though.. correct?

Comment: How can i add a parameter like `allowMissingColumns=True`?

Comment: DataFrame.unionAll is now deprecated. Use DataFrame.union instead

Comment: Wouldn't this be counterproductive to using spark as the reduce will write to disk?

Comment: `DataFrame.unionByName` is another option that should resolve by name rather than order.

Answer (score 2):

You can add parameters like **allowMissingColumns** by using reduce with lambda

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

dfs = [df1, df2]
df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.unionByName(y, allowMissingColumns=True), dfs)
```

Comment: I could not get why we use lambda here. I was doing without it and error thrown out. Basically , how does lambda made the difference. Can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

Under the Hood spark flattens union expressions. So it takes longer when the Union is done linearly.

The best solution is spark to have a union function that supports multiple DataFrames.

But the following code might speed up the union of multiple DataFrames (or DataSets)somewhat.

```
  def union[T : ClassTag](datasets : TraversableOnce[Dataset[T]]) : Dataset[T] = {
      binaryReduce[Dataset[T]](datasets, _.union(_))
  }
  def binaryReduce[T : ClassTag](ts : TraversableOnce[T], op: (T, T) => T) : T = {
      if (ts.isEmpty) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException
      }
      var array = ts toArray
      var size = array.size
      while(size > 1) {
         val newSize = (size + 1) / 2
         for (i <- 0 until newSize) {
             val index = i*2
             val index2 = index + 1
             if (index2 >= size) {
                array(i) = array(index)  // last remaining
             } else {
                array(i) = op(array(index), array(index2))
             }
         }
         size = newSize
     }
     array(0)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case some dataframes have missing columns, one can used a partially applied function:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

# Union dataframes by name (missing columns filled with null) 
union_by_name = partial(DataFrame.unionByName, allowMissingColumns=True)
df_output = reduce(union_by_name, [df1, df2, ...])
```