# How to union Spark SQL Dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here are several ways of creating a union of dataframes, which (if any) is best /recommended when we are talking about big dataframes? Should I create an empty dataframe first or continuously union to the first dataframe created?

**Empty Dataframe creation**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("A", StringType(), False), 
    StructField("B", StringType(), False), 
    StructField("C", StringType(), False)
])

pred_union_df = spark_context.parallelize([]).toDF(schema)
```

**Method 1 - Union as you go:**

```
for ind in indications:
    fitted_model = get_fitted_model(pipeline, train_balanced_df, ind)
    pred = get_predictions(fitted_model, pred_output_df, ind)
    pred_union_df  = pred_union_df.union(pred[['A', 'B', 'C']])
```

**Method 2 - Union at the end:**

```
all_pred = []
for ind in indications:
    fitted_model = get_fitted_model(pipeline, train_balanced_df, ind)
    pred = get_predictions(fitted_model, pred_output_df, ind)
    all_pred.append(pred)
pred_union_df = pred_union_df.union(all_pred)
```

Or do I have it all wrong?

**Edit:**
Method 2 was not possible as I thought it would be from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37612978/351204). I had to loop through the list and union each dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 2 is always preferred since it avoid the long lineage issue.

Although `DataFrame.union` only takes one DataFrame as argument, `RDD.union` does [take a list](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.union). Given your sample code, you could try to union them before calling `toDF`.

If your data is on disk, you could also try to [load them all at once](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) to achieve union, e.g.,

`dataframe = spark.read.csv([path1, path2, path3])`