# UNION multiple dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, union

I have number of `dataframes` that created inside a loop and I want to union all these `dataframes`. I tried to create final `dataframe' that should contains all other small`dataframes`, but it seams this not working because the union will hold only the last small`dataframes`. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612622/spark-unionall-multiple-dataframes) similar question and the answer that provided by @zero323 the solution that has been suggested works fine when I do it in shell:

```
scala> val a= sql("""select "1" as k""")
a: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [k: string]

scala> val b= sql("""select "2" as k""")
b: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [k: string]

scala> val c= sql("""select "3" as k""")
c: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [k: string]

scala> a.show
+---+
|  k|
+---+
|  1|
+---+


scala> b.show
+---+
|  k|
+---+
|  2|
+---+


scala> c.show
+---+
|  k|
+---+
|  3|
+---+
```

Now to join the above three `dataframes` I did the following:

```
scala> val g = Seq(a,b,c)
g: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = List([k: string], [k: string], [k: string])

scala> val s = g.reduce(_ union _)
s: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [k: string]

scala> s.show
+---+
|  k|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
+---+
```

**The problem**

Now I am trying to do same thing on Eclipse

```
val g = Seq()

    val dummyDf = ss.sql(s"select 0 as ss , a.* from table1 limit 1")
    for (element <- 0 to arr.size-1) {
      var strt: Int = arr.toList(element )
      var nd: Int = arr.toList(element + 1)
      val tempDF = ss.sql(s"select $strt as ss , a.* from table1 a where rnk between $strt+1 and $nd-1")
      g :+ tempDF
    }
val finalDf = g.reduce(_ union _)
```

but I got the following error message:

> Multiple markers at this line:
>
> ◾missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$14: , x$15)
>   ⇒ x$14.union(x$15))
>
> ◾identifier expected but '_' found.
>
> ◾missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$14: , x$15:
>   ) ⇒ x$14.union(x$15))

Any help with this is highly appreciated

**Edit:**

For the other solution that suggested in the link that I referred:

```
dfs match {
  case h :: Nil => Some(h)
  case h :: _   => Some(h.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
                     h.sqlContext.sparkContext.union(dfs.map(_.rdd)),
                     h.schema
                   ))
  case Nil  => None
}
```

where can I find the resulted union final `dataframe`? I ran it and the compilation went correctly, but I can not access the resulted `dataframe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where can I find the resulted union final dataframe? I ran it and the
>   compilation went correctly, but I can not access the resulted
>   dataframe

Answer :

This is the way to execute...
finaluniondf is `Option[DataFrame]` you have to use `.get` since its an `Option`

```
  package examples

    import org.apache.log4j.Level
    import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

    object DFUnion extends App {
      val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
      logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
      val spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName(this.getClass.getName)
        .config("spark.master", "local[*]").getOrCreate()

      import spark.implicits._
      import spark.sql
      val a= sql("""select "1" as k""")
      val b= sql("""select "2" as k""")
      val c= sql("""select "3" as k""")
      val dfs = Seq(a,b,c)
     val finaluniondf: Option[DataFrame] =  dfs match {
        case h :: Nil => Some(h)
        case h :: _   => Some(h.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
          h.sqlContext.sparkContext.union(dfs.map(_.rdd)),
          h.schema
        ))
        case Nil  => None
      }
      println("my final union df is ")
      finaluniondf.get.show
    }
```

Result :

```
my final union df is 
+---+
|  k|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
+---+
```

Comment: Hi @Ram. It work very well.  in the shell. The problem still in the Eclipse it though `value sqlContext is not a member of Nothing` error. BTW I edit my question and added the Eclipse code.

Comment: simple classpath or import issues have you tried that in intellij all needed dependencies are present in the classpath of eclipse ? all imports were done correctly as show above ?

Comment: try this in the first line of your program to identify any issues related to classpath `val cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader
    cl.asInstanceOf[java.net.URLClassLoader].getURLs.foreach(println)`

Comment: No did not try it in Intellij. Also I did try add the mentioned two lines of code but nothing changed

Comment: above 2 lines will print the classpath to understand what jars are  missing

Comment: So the program has an error now(the one that mentioned above), do you mean compile it with error? If so where I expect to see the name of missed jars(if any).

Comment: " has an error now " what s the error. you need to import java.net.URLClassLoader

Comment: Hello Ram, thanks for help. It complain on `case h :: _   => Some(h.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
          h.sqlContext.sparkContext.union(dfs.map(_.rdd))` the error message is `value sqlContext is not a member of Nothing` . However, I am wondering what is the wrong with the other method `reduce(_ union _)`

Comment: some where you assingned to wrong type thats why is not a member of Nothing

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the

`val g = Seq()`

I need to define the type of this Seq, otherwise `Scala` will give me `Nothing` as a type ( and that was the issue).

For that I did the following

`val tempDF = ss.sql(s"select 0 as ss , a.* from table1 a where rnk between $strt+1 and $nd-1")`

`val g = Seq(tempDF)`

By this the `g` will be `Seq[DataFrame]`

Thanks