# Vertically concatenate multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

So I'm trying to intertwine about 3 dataframes and the result should look like this:

df1

```
A

D

G
```

df2

```
B

E

H
```

df3

```
C

F

I
```

Resulting df:

```
A

B

C

D

E

F

G

H

I
```

I tried:

```
for i in len(df1+df2+df3):
    final_df.append(i)
```

I want to do this as efficiently as possible and with n dataframes

Answer (score 5):

Referring to [Spark unionAll multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612622/spark-unionall-multiple-dataframes):

You can simply put all the data frames into a list, and do a `unionAll` on them, like so:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)
```

You can concat as many dataframes as you want.