# Make single DataFrame from list of Dataframes

Tags: list, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, pyspark

I have a list of data frames,
on each location of a list, I have one dataframe
I need to combine all those in one dataframe.
this is to be done in PySpark ,
before I was using

```
dataframe_new =pd.concat(listName)
```

solution 1

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

import pyspark.sql

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row

customSchema = StructType([

  StructField("col1",      StringType(), True),

  StructField("col2", StringType(), True),

  StructField("col3", StringType(), True),

  StructField("col4",  StringType(), True),

  StructField("col5", StringType(), True),

  StructField("col6",  StringType(), True),

  StructField("col7", StringType(), True)

])



df = spark.createDataFrame(queried_dfs[0],schema=customSchema)
```

Solution 2 I tried: (iterating through the list of dataframes, but don't know how to combine them

```
for x in ListOfDataframe
    new_df=union_all()
```

but this is always create a new_df

any help to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark unionAll multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612622/spark-unionall-multiple-dataframes)

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful function for combining a list of dataframes even when the columns or order of columns are different

```
def Zconcat(dfs):
    return reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.union(df2.select(df1.columns)), dfs) 

def union_all(dfs):
    columns = reduce(lambda x, y : set(x).union(set(y)), [ i.columns for i in dfs ]  )

    for i in range(len(dfs)):
        d = dfs[i]
        for c in columns:
            if c not in d.columns:
                d = d.withColumn(c, lit(None))
        dfs[i] = d

    return Zconcat(dfs)
```

Then pass union_all a list of dataframes, e.g.

```
union_all([df1, df2, df3])
```