# How to merge dataframes in Databricks notebook using Python / Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks

I'm using a Databricks notebook to extract gz-zipped csv files and loading into a dataframe object. I'm having trouble with part 2 below.

Part 1: Loading zipped files into dataframe is running fine...

```
    %python
    df1 = spark.read.option("header",True).option("delimiter", "|").csv("dbfs:/model/.../file_1.csv.gz")
    df2 = spark.read.option("header",True).option("delimiter", "|").csv("dbfs:/model/.../file_2.csv.gz")
```

Part 2: Trying to merge the dataframes...

```
    %python
    import pandas as pd
    df =pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
    df.show(truncate=False)
```

... returns the following error:

*TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid*

Any suggestions for trying to modify how I'm merging the dataframes? I will have up to 20 files to merge, where all columns are the same.

Comment: Re-trying now by converting the objects to Pandas dataframes: df1 = df1.select("*").toPandas().... hoping this works, but objects are large and cluster is small'ish. TBD soon i hope.

Comment: concat is supported in pandas but not in spark, you should explore `df1.union(df2)` instead. pandas and pyspark arent the same, `.toPandas()` might work but its not efficient/might not fit to memory when your df size gets big

Comment: for multiple dfs try reduce `from pyspark.sql import DataFrame` and then `reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, [df1,df2,df3])`

Comment: related [spark unionAll multiple dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612622/spark-unionall-multiple-dataframes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If objects are large I don't think the best approach is to convert from `pyspark` to `pandas`, but to perform the equivalent of `concat` in `pyspark`.

**Note that**  `unionAll()` is deprecated since Spark “2.0.0” version and replaced with `union()` https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-union-and-unionall/

I believe you could do:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

dfs = [df1,df2]
merged = reduce(DataFrame.union, dfs)
```

And of course to view it:

```
merged.show(truncate=False) # or display(merged)
```

Comment: You were all correct, converting to pandas failed miserably. The solution above works great, thank you.